# Efficient 50% randomly Choosing value from one of two dataframe columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, random, bigdata

I have a big dataframe (the following is just an example):
I would like to randomly choose (with probabiluty of 50%) either the value of `X1` or `X2`.

```
> df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=7))
> df
           X1         X2
1   0.7091409 -1.4061361
2  -1.1334614 -0.1973846
3   2.3343391 -0.4385071
4  -0.9040278 -0.6593677
5   0.4180331 -1.2592415
6   0.7572246 -0.5463655
7  -0.8996483  0.4231117
```

I would like to randomly choose either from X1 or X2 and add it to as new column.

The result should look something like that:

```
 > df
               X1         X2     RC
    1   0.7091409 -1.4061361    -1.4061361
    2  -1.1334614 -0.1973846    -1.1334614
    3   2.3343391 -0.4385071    -0.4385071
    4  -0.9040278 -0.6593677    -0.6593677
    5   0.4180331 -1.2592415     0.4180331
    6   0.7572246 -0.5463655     0.7572246
    7  -0.8996483  0.4231117     0.4231117
```

What is the most efficient way to do it for big data dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usual `ifelse` with `runif` function  works quite well. In case of 100 000 000 rows in data frame it takes couple of seconds on 8 GB RAM laptop.

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200000000), nrow=100000000))
df$RC <- ifelse(runif(nrow(df)) > 0.5, df$X1,df$X2)
```

Comment: I have 2 dataframes (with same nrows). One df1$X1 and the other df2$X2. Should it work the same?

Comment: Yes. Inupts df$X1 and df$X2 in `ifelse` function are vectors just like df1$X1 and df2$X2.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow it inserts a value that doesnot appear in each of dataframes. Is there a to add randomness per row (0 or 1) and to choose relatively?

Comment: This is the df$RC:  [1] 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1
and this the first df$X1:  [1] 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
And this is df$X2: [1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 Why is it?

Comment: Both df$X1 and df$X2 are factors. Is there a way to keep their same original values?

Comment: If you want to keep original values convert your factors to numeric values first `df$X1 <- as.numeric(levels(df$X1))[df$X1]
df$X2 <- as.numeric(levels(df$X2))[df$X2]`.